# How can I write a single constructor method to set two fields to a specific value

Tags: c#

I am learning about writing constructors and properties in c# and was asked to write a console app and class to operate a beverage machine. I wrote part of the class code but ran into an issue. One of the many blocks of code asks for a constructor method that starts the `SodaCanCount` at 5 bottles and sets the `CustBalance` field to zero. I don't know what this constructor should look like. I am specifically talking about the `private sodaVandorClass()`, right under the two private fields.

I wrote what I could so far and I have no errors however the `SodaVendorClass` does not look right.

```
namespace VendorClass
{
  public class SodaVendorClass
  {
    // members 

    // fields
    //Customer balance is $0 until the customer inserts a dollar
    //All customer entries are one dollar increments and a soda   costs one dollar.
    private int CustBalance = 0;
    //a machine holds 10 cans of soda
    private int SodaCanCount = 5;

     //A soda costs 1 dollar
    //private int sodaCost = 1;


    public int _SodaCanCount
    {
        get
        {
            return SodaCanCount;
        }
    }

    public int _CustBalance
    {
        get
        {
            return CustBalance;
        }
    }


   public int BuySoda(int pCustBalance, int SodaCanCount)
   {
       return SodaCanCount;
   }

    public void AcceptCash(int CustBalance)
    {
        CustBalance++;
    }
    public int GiveRefund(int pCustBalance)
    {
        return CustBalance;
    }
}
```

I only want to see an example of a constructor that sets default values for my private class fields. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There's nothing special about your code which would prohibit you from writing a standard constructor like in [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors)

Comment: *"I don't know what this constructor should look like"* - how do you learn C# exactly? Any tutorial/book explaining constructors will give enough knowledge to do that.

Comment: Sorry, my original post had a constructor that I wrote but it seems to have been edited out. I was just attempting to get help because it didn't look right to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a `public` constructor like below but probably you don't need one if you enable your properties to set values too

```
public SodaVendorClass()
{
  this.CustBalance = 0;
  this.SodaCanCount = 0; 
}
```

You can make your properties writable too. Notice below are auto properties and in such case you don't need those `private` backing fields explicitly.

```
public int SodaCanCount
{
  get; set;
}

public int CustBalance
{
  get; set;
}
```

You can instantiate your type saying (using *Object Initializer* construct)

```
 SodaVendorClass sc = new SodaVendorClass
 {
   SodaCanCount = 10,
   CustBalance = 500,
 };
```

Comment: Thank you, this constructor looks similar to the one that I wrote before the post was edited. (I think I made it too long winded) Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

A constructor for this class could look like this:

```
public SodaVendorClass () {
}
```

That would be an empty constructor that does nothing.

To set the two values you want, you can add some paramters:

```
public SodaVendorClass (int customerBalance, int sodaCount) {
    this.CustBalance = customerBalance;
    this.SodaCanCount = sodaCount;
}
```

To create an instance of this class with 5 soda cans and a customer balance of 0, you would call the constructor in the code like this:

```
var vendor = new SodaVendorClass(0, 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace VendorClass 
{
   public class SodaVendorClass 
   {
       private int CustBalance;
       private int SodaCanCount;
       //...
       public SodaVendorClass() // default constuctor
       {
           CustBalance = 0;
           SodaCanCount = 5;
       }
       //...
   }
}
```

Default constructor is called when you are creating object like this:

```
SodaVendorClass obj = new SodaVendorClass();
```

So `obj._SodaCanCount` is 5 and `obj._CustBalance` is 0
Also you can define constructor with parameters.

```
public SodaVendorClass(int balance, int count)
{
    CustBalance = balance;
    SodaCanCount = count;
}
```

and create call this constructor.

```
SodaVendorClass obj = new SodaVendorClass(0, 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

A constructor is being used while creating a object like "Class obj=new Calss()". If you don define a constructor in your class a default constructor will be provided implicitly.User defined Constructor usually used for initializing value for class properties. Unlike function constructor does not have any return type at all not even void. All the answers are good.

```
public class SodaVendorClass{
  private int CustBalance = 0;
//a machine holds 10 cans of soda
private int SodaCanCount = 5;

 //A soda costs 1 dollar
//private int sodaCost = 1;


public int _SodaCanCount
{
    get
    {
        return SodaCanCount;
    }
}

public int _CustBalance
{
    get
    {
        return CustBalance;
    }
}
 public SodaVendorClass(int cancount, int sodacost){
   SodaCanCount=cancount;
   sodaCost=sodacost;
 }
}

//creating a object of Sodavendorclass
Sodavendorclass obj=new Sodavendorclass(0,0); //Provided value for class property
```

Notice that at the time of object creation, provided for Property. This is one of the way you can use constructor.